# How do I work with a Detail page in a master/detail scenario using Panels?

Tags: panels

This has me stumped.  I'm using panels and have created a view for my 10 classic cars.  This works perfectly, but in your view, you click on the title and in my case, the image/car also, and that takes you to the main/rest/full content.  I am stuck here,

I need to create another panel to display this "detail page", but I will want this same page/panel called when someone clicks on any of the ten cars. Just the new car and new related datail appearing

I don't want to create a panel for each car and I know I don't have to but I can't figure out how I would accomplish this using panels.

So in short, I have a view, that I have placed in a panel, and it displays a small image of my 10 cars, and the corresponding title and teaser text for each.  When user clicks on the title, it should open the detail page which is a new panel page I have created displaying the info/data related to the car that was clicked.

I am sure this is going to be one of those "duh" moments, because I think I know it is pretty basic functionality, but I just can't pull it together.